# systemd ExecStartPost is executed too fast

Tags: linux, systemctl

We have a unit file which:

uses `ExecStartPre` which generates a config file
`ExecStart` uses the config file to start a service
`ExecStartPost` which deletes the file created by `ExecStartPre`. (the file has hardcoded passwords and we do not want to keep it on disk. so it must only exist while the service is being started or restarted.

If the service is started successfully it should delete the config file, if the service fails to start it should also delete the file.

this is the systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus Server
Documentation=https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=prommgr
Group=secapm
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python2 /prom/config/anon_yml.py
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/prom/appl/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/prom/config/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prom/data --web.listen-address=127.0.0.1:9090  --storage.tsdb.retention.time=1825d &>>/prom/logs/prometheus.log"
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/python2 anon_yml.py --delete 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the config file in question is prometheus.yml
the script `anon_yml.py` will create the file from a jinja template and populate it with the needed passwords.
`ExecStart` will then start the service

in theory `ExecStartPost` would then remove the prometheus.yml file from disk after ExecStart has finished, however when the service is being restarted i have errors of config file is missing. it only means ExecStartPost did not wait until ExecStart finished.

How to make sure the config file is only deleted after the process has already been restarted?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `ExecStartPost=` executes too fast is because your service is of `Type=simple` (the default when `ExecStart=` is specified but `Type=` is omitted). In this case, `ExecStartPost=` will execute right after the process in `ExecStart=` is started.

If you want `ExecStartPost=` to execute only after the last `ExecStart=` process exited successfully, then you need to change your service to `Type=oneshot`:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
...
```

Answer (score 0):

use like a flag to check if your Post action can be executed or not.

- append to the ExecStart cmd:

`&& touch /tmp/flag`

- replace ExecStartPost with:

`timeout 10 bash -c -- 'while test ! -f /tmp/flag; do /usr/bin/python2 anon_yml.py --delete && rm -f /tmp/flag ; sleep 1; done'`

it looks a bit dirty but should work..

Comment: yeah but i am more interested to know why systemd starts it too soon? is it because of the type simple and the fact that the ExecStart is with /bin/sh -c .... 
I could add indeed sleep and other hacks, per instalce i can append `&& rm -rf` to ExecStart.